# Avoid the carriage return when writing InnerText in xml elements using System.Xml.XmlWriter

Tags: .net, xml, xmlwriter, innertext

I'm using XmlWriter to save an XmlDocument in .Net. However all the elements that have InnerText are written with surrounding carriage return characters.

I tried using XmlWriterSettings to avoid the writing of those characters, but no luck yet.

Here it is a piece of code used:

```
        XmlDocument outXml = new XmlDocument();
        outXml.AppendChild .......
        XmlWriterSettings sets = new XmlWriterSettings();
        sets.Encoding = encoding;
        sets.Indent = true;
        XmlWriter xwriter = XmlWriter.Create(file, sets);
        outXml.Save(xwriter);
        xwriter.Close();
```

The xml output is like:

```
  <String Id="msierrXmlFileFailedSave" Overridable="yes">
    Fehler beim Speichern der Einstellungen-Datei.
  </String>
```

The xml output needed should be like:

```
  <String Id="msierrXmlFileFailedSave" Overridable="yes">Fehler beim Speichern der Einstellungen-Datei.</String>
```

Is there a way to avoid the writing of those carriage returns inside the elements?

PD: I saw an [opposite question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276243/carriage-return-in-xmlnode-innertext) about this issue, but the solution does not apply to this case.

Thanks in advance.

Allan.c

Comment: possible duplicate of [XMLDocument.Save adds return carriages to XML when elements are blank](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19258810/xmldocument-save-adds-return-carriages-to-xml-when-elements-are-blank)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to set the [XmlDocument.PreserveWhitespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.preservewhitespace.aspx) property before calling Save. Another option is to use CData sections instead of inner text where the text content of the elements needs to be preserved exactly.

From the documentation:

> If PreserveWhitespace is true before
>   Load or LoadXml is called, white space
>   nodes are preserved; otherwise, if
>   this property is false, significant
>   white space is preserved, white space
>   is not.
>
> If PreserveWhitespace is true before
>   Save is called, white space in the
>   document is preserved in the output;
>   otherwise, if this property is false,
>   XmlDocument auto-indents the output.