# displaying text from InnerText

Tags: asp.net, html, xml

When I try and display text from an the InnerText from an XML element. I get something like this:

> I need this spacing \r\n\r\n\r\second lot of spacing\r\n\r\nMore spacing\r\n\r\n

I know you can replace `\r\n` with  `<br>` but is there no function that automatically takes the html for you and why does it use `\r` and `\n`? Many thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Carriage return in XmlNode Innertext](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276243/carriage-return-in-xmlnode-innertext)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `<pre>` tag - it will show the text as-is like you see it in text editor:

For example:

```
<pre><%=MyText%></pre>
```

Better practice for ASP.NET is:

```
<pre id="myPlaceholder" runat="server"></pre>
```

Then assign its value from code behind:

```
myPlaceholder.InnerHtml = MyText;
```

As for your question "why does it use `\r` and `\n`" those are carriage return and line feed characters, aka newline characters - when you have such text:

```
line 1
line 2
```

Then code reading it will give: `line1\nline2` or `line1\r\nline2` depending on how it's stored exactly.